# Is there any way to claim an abandoned Twitter name?

Tags: twitter, account-management, username

I've been in the process of trying to switch over my username on various online services to a common name. I've been fortunate to get most of the ones I want (GMail, Facebook) but one that has eluded me is Twitter. The user on twitter having the username I want sent a single tweet over two years ago and nothing else. He doesn't follow anyone, and doesn't have any followers. Even the account that he replied to no longer exists.

By and large, it's a waste of a perfectly good Twitter handle, one which I would very much like to use. Is there any way to get Twitter to release the name so that I can use it for myself?

Answer (score 5):

Following a Twitter Employee : [@Delbius](http://twitter.com/delbius) (Del Harvey), it seems you can try to submit a [Twicket](http://support.twitter.com/forms) to request the name.

> *[...] @support releases accounts when they can for inactivity.*
>   <sub>https://twitter.com/#!/delbius/status/63639677932019713</sub>

Comment: It's encouraging that that tweet is only a few hours old. A lot of the material online about getting access to abandoned usernames can be years out of date. That said, I did submit a ticket and I got back an automated reply that "f you're looking to acquire an inactive username for personal use, please check back in a few months. We're currently unable to accommodate individual requests for inactive usernames. We may release all inactive usernames in the future, but have not yet set a date for doing so". The ticket is still "in progress", so I just might be able to get a real response as well.

Comment: Just checked and my ticket has been closed, but the account I want is still active.

Answer (score 3):

Reading what is [there](http://thenextweb.com/2009/01/08/how-to-snap-up-that-twitter-username-youve-always-wanted/), it seems that usernames are released after 9 months of inactivity.It was apparently not the case for the one you want.
You should try contacting username@twitter.com to push them releasing this account and let you use it instead.

Comment: I actually found that article months ago and emailed them without success. I've tried again, this time submitting a ticket with the software instead of emailing.

Comment: That email address isn't even monitored any more, no use trying that.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter is not releasing accounts for personal use anymore even if if they haven been inactive for years. You only have a chance if [you can prove a trademark violation](https://support.twitter.com/articles/18367-trademark-policy).